# Resume File Upload from User's machine to Azure Blob Storage and Download file from Azure Blob to User's machine in Typescript(angular) from Browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-blob-storage, resume-download

I am very new to Angular. Can anyone please help me how can I **RESUME** file upload from User's machine to Azure Blob Storage and download file from Azure Blob to user's machine in Typescript(angular) from Browser. I am using @azure/storage-blob npm library to upload/download files to Azure Blob.

Comment: follow these document to upload and download file.

Upload file from usermachine to Azureblob : https://stuarttottle.medium.com/upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-angular-7977e979496a
Download file from blob storage to user machine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blob-file-download?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Is there any way to pause the upload file and resume it later after the sasToken has expired?